# Disk write issue but no error detected

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, io

I'm using a 3TB western digital red disk on my desktop pc (windows 10) and smart info says it's been powered on for nearly 1000 days,
I never had any issue with it before but now I'm having some random problems and windows won't detect anything nor chkdsk and a full read check with "easis drive check" tool,
so basically I found out there was a problem when first trying to download some ~500MB PS4 update file,
the file would download with no error but the PS4 was always reporting the file as corrupted, I did it twice with no luck,
then I downloaded the same file on my system SSD and comparing the files I saw some chunks of the corrupted files were empty "0",
I forgot about this for some days then yesterday while doing some video extraction and muxing I found one the extracted audio files got corrupted with a big empty chunk of data, extracting the same audio file to the SSD was OK,
same thing when trying to download some big nvidia drivers but this time chrome just stopped downloading randomly.

Could someone please help to diagnose this ?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like the drive is starting to fail and should be replaced.

Comment: you should use paragraphs in your question so it's easier to understand.

Comment: I had some line breaks but looks like it was removed automatically ^^

Answer (score 0):

Diagnostic tests for drive behavior don't always find errors. When they do, great, you know it's drive replacement time. However, sometimes they don't detect failures, yet you clearly have symptoms of a failing drive. Please back up everything immediately, and acquire a new drive.

Comment: Thanks I'm copying everything to a new drive already :)